# define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface

Tags: go, protobuf-go

2023/08/23 15:24:39 C:/Code/vblog/skill/rpc/protobuf/blog/impl/blog.go:19
[error] invalid field found for struct protobuf/blog.Blog's field Meta: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface

```
message Meta {
    int64 id = 1;
    int64 created_at = 2;
    int64 updated_at = 3;
}
message Blog {
    // @gotags: gorm:"embedded" json:"meta" bson:",inline"
    Meta meta = 1;
    // 具体请求数据
    CreateBlogRequest spec = 2;
}
```

```
func NewMeta() *Meta {
    return &Meta{CreatedAt: time.Now().Unix()}
}

func NewBlog(req *CreateBlogRequest) *Blog {
    return &Blog{Meta: NewMeta(), Spec: req}
}
type Blog struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    // @gotags: gorm:"embedded" json:"meta" bson:",inline"
    Meta *Meta `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=meta,proto3" json:"meta,omitempty"`
    // 具体请求数据
    Spec *CreateBlogRequest `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=spec,proto3" json:"spec,omitempty"`
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

你有 // @gotags: gorm:"embedded"，  但没有运行命令：protoc-go-inject-tag  -input=*.pb.go
，看这里可以发现：
// @gotags: gorm:"embedded" json:"meta" bson:",inline"
Meta *Meta `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=meta,proto3" json:"meta,omitempty"`
在tag中，没有 gorm:"embedded"

english:
You have//@ gotags: gorm: "embedded", but did not run the command: protoc go object tag input=*. pb.go
Here you can find:
//@ gotags: gorm: "embedded" JSON: "meta" JSON: ", inline"
Meta * Meta  `protobuf: "bytes, 1, opt, name=meta, proto3" JSON: "meta, omitty"`
In the tag, there is no gorm: "embedded"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).